# MySqlSyntaxErrorException wrong Query

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm tring to create a table in mysql from java desktop program but I obtain a MySqlSyntaxErrorException.

The query is :

```
CREATE TABLE FileXFascia(fila0 Integer,fila1 Integer,fila2 Integer,fila3 Integer) VALUES ('3','4','3','3')
```

Anyone knows where I'm wrong?

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'VALUES ('3','4','3','3')'` at line 1

Comment: I don't really know my mysql syntax, but what are you trying to do here? Create the table _and_ insert values? Shouldn't `VALUES` be used with an `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: Don't you mean `INSERT INTO` instead of `CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split these as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE FileXFascia(fila0 Integer,fila1 Integer,fila2 Integer,fila3 Integer); 
INSERT INTO FileXFascial (fila0, fila1, fila2, fila3) VALUES ('3','4','3','3');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question there are two different operations on a table, You are trying to create and insert data in single query even in a wrong way. First you need to create table then insert data into created table. Like below syntax.

```
create table tableName(col1 dataType,col2 dataType,col3 dataType,.......coln dataType);
```

After creation of table now you can insert data into table. Like  below syntax.

```
insert into tableName(col1, col2,col3,......coln) values ('data1','data2','data3',......'datan');
```